# Using jpda to connect to weblogic

Tags: java, jvmti, jpda, jdi

I am building a utility/tool to profile/trace the method calls in a Java EE application deployed in Weblogic 10 (java 6). The intention is to quickly understand the flow of events in our huge enterprise application. (Going through the code is tedious)

I have followed the "Trace" demo application that is bundled with jdk6 to build my version. The application works fine while connecting to a normal desktop style application and successfully tracing the method calls. But for Weblogic, EventQueue.remove is returning null EventSet. Please note that the connection to weblogic VM is successful. But as soon as it is connected, any click or activity in the deployed web application will cause the thread in target VM to hang and eventually the http request times out.

I am using the following vm arguments for weblogic start script:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE \
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=9002,suspend=n
```

Sample code used is from jdk1.6.0_13\demo\jpda\examples\com\sun\tools\example\trace

Does anybody has experience with similar tools or faced similar issues. I wonder how Eclipse remote debugging is implemented!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to see what the problem is by logging at JDWP layer.
Use a TCP packet sniffer for your OS.
You may have to run your debugger on a different machine in order to capture the traffic.
It is easy to decode the packets by just using the JDWP spec.
If just analyzing does not help, you can compare your JDWP traffic with the one from Eclipse or from your working scenario.
I have seen the Eclipse debugger to appear hung when flooding the connection with unloaded class events.